# Make irssi-xmpp show me as using mobile when connected to Gmail/Google Talk

Tags: gmail, irssi, xmpp

I've set up [GTalk via the irssi-xmpp plugin](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=17703) but it currently lists me as plain online in Gmail. I'd like to see if I can make it show me as if I am on mobile.

As far as I can tell, users on Android have cloaks (not sure if this is the correct term) of the form `something@gmail.com/androidece4cecb2b8e`. For example, one entry in the `/roster` was

```
Firsname Lastname [something@gmail.com/androidece4cecb2b8e]: is now Away
```

my own entry is

```
myemail@Gmail.com/Gmail.D6C87CCF: is now Available [My status here]
```

This seems to be the XMPP equivalent of an IRC cloak.

How can I change this? Or is there some other way into tricking the server show that I am on mobile?

Comment: If anyone has a similar solution for Facebook, that would help too.